# Create Items in Sharepoint with Xamarin and Microsoft Graph

Tags: sharepoint, xamarin, office365api, microsoft-graph-api

Can somebody explain to me how to create Items in `Sharepoint` with `Microsoft Graph`?

I used this repro [IgniteBrk3114](https://github.com/fabianwilliams/ignitebrk3114)

And get `Infos` with

```
var response = await client.GetStringAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sharepoint/site/drive/items/root/children?$select=name");
```

Can I push with `PostAsync` now at the same way?

```
var postResult = await client.PostAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sharepoint/site/drive/items/root/children", contents);
```

Or is it the wrong way? Do I need `SharePointClient()` to change?
I also saw this [Add Collaboration To Your Mobile Apps with SharePoint](https://blog.xamarin.com/add-collaboration-to-your-mobile-apps-with-sharepoint/), but it dont work right now.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to create a file in a Document Library in the SharePoint root site. If that's what you're trying to do, you the syntax is a little different:

```
var requestUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sharePoint/site/drive/root/children/filename.txt/content";
var requestData = new StreamContent(fileStream) // HttpContent with file contents
var response = await client.PutAsyc(requestUrl, requestData);
```

POSTing to the children collection is not supported on SharePoint / OneDrive for Business.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Graph, Post and Sharepoint isnt supportet yet
https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/sharepoint